# Analog Devices chip identification Y 4 A

Tags: integrated-circuit

I've been trying to identify this little fellow:

[image]

The symbol indicates Analog devices. But the Cryptic "Y 4 A" is giving me a headache. Ive searched throughout the internet for the labelling norms of AD but I can't find it. Everything that is explained relates to ADXXXX... something. No word about single char labelling.

I'm sorry for the bad resolution, but I can't provide a better picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By searching `"Y4A" site:analog.com` I found [this datasheet](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD8421.pdf) which seems pretty close.

Comment: Thank you! I wish one would learn how to use a search engine properly at school!